# PySerial Attributes - Issues, Documentation Current Reference?

Tags: python, pyserial

I am very new, learning Python specifically geared toward hardware (serial port and TCP/IP device) testing.

I have been trying to get PySerial based code to work and keep hitting roadblocks.  Running Python 3.10.8 on Windows 10.

I worked through the 'import serial' problem (uninstalled and reinstalled Python); the serial.Serial problem (needed to add 'from serial import *).  Now, it seems like all of the read syntax does not work.  All I want to do at this point is open the port, read and print data - from here I will start working on which data I want).

Here is the code I am working with (this was found in a couple of places on the internet):

```
#test_sport
import serial
from serial import *
s = serial.Serial(port='COM9', baudrate=9600)
serial_string = ""
                   
while(1):

    # Wait until there is data waiting in the serial buffer
    if(serialPort.in_waiting > 0):

        # Read data out of the buffer until a carraige return / new line is found
        serial_string = serial.readline()

        # Print the contents of the serial data
        print(serial_string.decode('Ascii'))

        # Tell the device connected over the serial port that we recevied the data!
        # The b at the beginning is used to indicate bytes!
        #serialPort.write(b"Thank you for sending data \r\n")
```

Running this results in an error on serialPort.in_waiting (says serialPort not defined) if I change that to serial.in_waiting (says  serial has no attribute 'in_waiting' (PySerial API site says this is correct(?).  I've also tried simple commands like serial.read(), serial.readline(), ser.read(), etc.  All fail for attributes.

Is the PySerial documentation online current?  Does anyone know where to find basic serial port examples?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, that didn't take long.  I see the issue, I needed to use statements this way ```s.in_waiting``` .  Now it works (bombs out on the ascii translations, need to work that).

Comment: Your first problem is that you don't seem to know Python (enough). Before you can use any Python libraries in a meaningful way you have to learn the fundamentals of the language or you will keep hitting "roadblocks" every 5 minutes.

Comment: This is the current documentation of pySerial: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/